# How to calculate progressively using python

Tags: python

I am creating a fitness wearable device python program that tracks the distance its users walk or run daily. To motivate the users to meet and exceed the target distance, it rewards users with fitness points on a leadership board for the users who meet and exceed the target distance in a week.

The fitness point is calculated with a minimum distance of 32 km per week, and the points for each km in excess of the minimum distance is show as follow:

- Distance: 0 to 32 km Fitness Point: 0
- Distance: 33 to 40 km Fitness Point:325 points per km
- Distance: 41 to 48 km Fitness Point: 550 points per km
- Distance: Greater than 48 km Point: 600 points per km

How do I make the points calculate progressively.

```
def fitness_app(distance):
    while True:
        distance = int(input("Please Enter Distance in Km: "))
        if 0 > distance < 32:
            fitness_pt = 0
            print(fitness_pt)
        elif 33 > distance < 40:
            fitness_pt = 325 * distance
            print(fitness_pt)
        elif 41 > distance < 48:
            fitness_pt = 550 * distance
            print(fitness_pt)
        elif distance > 48:
            fitness_pt = 600 * distance
            print(fitness_pt)


print(fitness_app(distance=True))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "progressively"? If somebody does 48km, is the idea that 48 km should be worth something like (32 * 0) + ((40 - 32) * 325) + ((48 - 40) * 550)?

Comment: I think your conditions are wrong: to denote an interval the inequality symbols should stay the same: `0 < distance < 32` otherwise is always `False`

Comment: Lots of bugs here: fitness_app never ends, fitness_app never returns a value, distance passed as boolean is unused, boolean tests are wrong (as mentioned in above comment).

Comment: yes chris is right but I do not know how to put it in the function @Chris

Comment: @rikochua, I formulated my comment that way on purpose. It should give you a hint about how you can implement this. Where would you plug the total kilometers into that formula? Why did I show (40 - 32) and (48 - 40)? Why does 40 appear twice?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're almost there, just that the comparisons don't need to be so complicated:

```py
def fitness_app():
    while True:
        distance = int(input("Please Enter Distance in Km: "))
        if distance < 32:
            fitness_pt = 0
        elif distance < 40:
            fitness_pt = 325 * distance
        elif distance < 48:
            fitness_pt = 550 * distance
        else:
            fitness_pt = 600 * distance
        print(fitness_pt)


fitness_app()
```

Note: other superfluous complications also removed.

Comment: Suspect this doesn't solve the, admittedly unclear, need for progressive rewards.

Comment: @jarmod: I guess you have a particular notion of what `progressive` is. I just took the text description of points per km as the meaning of progressive. Still, if the OP ever comments we both may learn something.

Comment: I'm assuming *progressive* as in [progressive tax](https://www.extension.iastate.edu/agdm/wholefarm/html/c5-212.html) but agree that we don't know that's the OP's intention.